# Can scalameter be imported to scala3 projects (and how)?

Tags: scala, sbt, benchmarking, scala-3, scalameter

I tried to use scalameter 0.21 (and some other versions) with scala 3.1.2.
I added some configurations from [the scalameter web-page](https://scalameter.github.io/home/gettingstarted/0.7/sbt/) in my build.sbt file and tried serveral things to make this work, but sbt was not able to find the desired packages.
I would have concluded that scalameter is simply not available for scala3, but there is a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68941194/range-benchmark-sluggish-after-migrating-to-scala3) where somebody somehow got it to work.

The problem seemed to bee that sbt added a 3 in all the sources, as in:

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/storm-enroute/scalameter_3/0.21/scalameter_3-0.21.pom

but the path with scalameter_3 did not exist. If I change the scalaversion to 2.13.8, sbt is able to download all the nesessary files without error. Starting with scala version 3.0.0 the problem exists.

If somebody could post a build.sbt file where scalameter and scala3 are used together, I would apreciate it.

Otherwise, if somebody knows a different library for benchmarking with scala 3...

Thanks very much

Comment: You can specify and use cross-configuration and use 2_13 version for scala 3. Search for "Using Scala 2.13 libraries in Scala 3" in https://scala-lang.org/blog/2021/04/08/scala-3-in-sbt.html . You should add ".cross(CrossVersion.for3Use2_13)" to you library depenency and it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @maxkar mentioned, using `crossVersion` should do the job:

```
("com.storm-enroute" %% "scalameter" % "0.21").cross(CrossVersion.for3Use2_13) % Test
```

However, doing so, you may encounter a problem with conflicting dependencies, e.g.:

```
[error] Modules were resolved with conflicting cross-version suffixes in ProjectRef(...
[error]    org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml _2.13, _3
```

In such a case, dependency exclusion, as described in sbt [documentation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Management.html#Exclude+Transitive+Dependencies), should solve the issue:

```
("com.storm-enroute" %% "scalameter" % "0.21").cross(CrossVersion.for3Use2_13) % Test exclude("org.scala-lang.modules", "scala-xml_2.13")
```

I'm not sure if this cannot backfire in certain situations, but it worked perfectly in my case.